# Как подобрать паттерн проектирования

Tags: java, ооп, сокеты, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть два модуля. Один клиент, второй сервер. Общаются они на сокетах. В третьем модуле лежат классы, которые используют оба предыдущих модуля.

Если конкретнее, то приложение представляет собой "магазин" - есть каталог, в каталоге есть категории, в категориях товары. Можно оформлять заказ - добавляем туда товары, выставляем время приготовления.

Так вот: как красиво оформить **архитектуру такого приложения** на сокетах? Не могу подобрать паттерн, а может, он и не нужен вовсе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопросик решился паттерном `Mediator` с двумя методами:

```
public void sendMsg(OutputStream, Object msg) {...} 

public Object acceptMsg(InputStream) {...}
```

Я его засунула в модуль с общими классами и в итоге получилось воспольщоваться им и на клиенте, и на сервере.

Надеюсь, кому то поможет

Answer (score 2):

Одним патерном работу не описать, вот например модули которые вы пишите отдельно друг от друга-ето уже некий патерн например **"Мост"**, потом вы все ето где-то используете и предоставляете доступ клиенту через определеные речаги, патерн **"Фасад"** который вы используете неявно, а то что вы делаете с обьктами и
то какие уже готовые обькты вы используете их связь друг с другом, и есть те самые патерны.